# @FindBy finding webelement returns null

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I'm using @FindBy annotation in my selenium code

```
@FindBy(how=How.ID, using = "username")
public WebElement username;
```

`System.out.println(username);` - it is printing null
`searchBox.sendKeys("test");` - throwing "java.lang.NullPointerException"

And username webelement need to be send to another class to check visibility of it, before performing some action on it.

```
public static WebElement waitAndFindElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int timeOutInSeconds){
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,timeOutInSeconds);
WebElement e = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
return e;
}
```

Nothing is working for me..

Comment: Show us the HTML of that element.

Comment: <li>
<label for="UserName">Username:</label>
<input id="username" class="fields" name="username">
</li>
<li>
<label for="Password">Password:</label>
<input id="password" type="password" name="password">
</li>

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you didn't call `PageFactory.initElements();`

Please refer to [PageFactory documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) for more details.

As you haven't post your page class which contains the elements, so I can't give you the best answer on where to put it (in general, it will be inside page object's constructor or after page object's initialization).

Comment: @Rob Murphy: Do you have any feedback on this? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the locator argument inside the visibilityOf method()

WebElement e = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.id(locatorArg)));

If you dont pass the value then how can webdriver locate the element.